# What is wrong with my linked list DeleteAt Function?

Tags: c#, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to delete a node in the linked list and when I performed this code, it removes all the nodes which are before the index I gave. Is there a way that I can correct it?

```
public void DeleteAt(int index)
        {
            if (index == 0)
            {
                head = head.next;
            }
            else
            {
                Node a = head;
                Node n1 = null;

                for(int i=0; i<index-1; i++)
                {
                    n1 = a.next;
                    a.next = n1.next;

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Firstly, do you understand what a for loop is?  Secondly, Do you know understand what a linked list is? Thirdly, do you know how to debug an application? As it seems in a least one of these cases you are confused, which is why you cant solve this

Comment: I see two issues here.
1) You should iterate till you find the index you want to remove from the linked list
2) After find the node you want to delete,break the link and make the new connection

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is removing a node in *each* iteration. You should only do this once, *after* the loop.

Secondly, you should protect your code against dereferencing `NULL` values.

NB: ...and use variable names that are descriptive. `a` and `n1` are cryptic; that does not help anyone that tries to understand your code. `i` is an exception, as it is common to name an integer loop variable like that.

```
public void DeleteAt(int index)
{
    if (head == NULL) // List is empty; nothing to do
    {
        return;
    }
    if (index == 0)
    {
        head = head.next;
    }
    else
    {
        Node node = head;

        for(int i=0; i<index-1; i++)
        {
            node = node.next;
            if (node == NULL) { // Index is out of range
                return;
            }
        }
        if (node.next != NULL) { // Index is not out of range
            node.next = node.next.next;
        }
    }
}
```